# Lost VB6 source code; is it possible to override methods in another object?

Tags: .net, inheritance, com, vb6, interop

I know a company that lost its source code to a VB6 DLL that exposes COM.  Is it possible to wrap, or orverride properties, methods, etc of this object to be more modern?

What technology should I use?  What approaches should I take?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: We have VS2010, and any other version we need.  What are you thoughts @Kris

Comment: You should be fine with VS2010.  Let us know what you decided to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would wrap it in a new C# class and expose only minimum functionality to the calling code (probably via an interface).  This way, some functionally can be gradually rewritten in C# without affecting the calling client.

And yes, utilize interop to create a runtime-callable wrapper.

Calling .NET code -> your new .NET class wrapper -> the COM dll via the runtime-callable wrapper.

Now even though you are not literally overriding functions or properties... you can still accomplish this via your wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the COM object in a runtime-callable wrapper. This will allow you to access the methods on the COM interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx